# drupal 7: module-theme-combination searched for 'single-page-application' + 'responsive-design'

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, responsive-design, drupal-themes, single-page-application

I have to build a drupal 7 website

- as a singe page web application
- with responsive web design.

Which module-theme-combination would suit to get the job done?

What I've tried so far:

- Single_Page_Website (Module) + Omega (Theme) | doesn't work
- Single_Page_Website (Module) + Responsive Bartik (Theme) | doesn't work

It seems that the Single_Page_Website module only supports the non-responsive Bartik theme. I cannot switch to the OnePage distribution in case you might suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [Quicktabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) with some nice styling, in conjunction with maybe [Bootstrap](http://drupal.org/project/bootstrap) or Zurb Foundations.

Answer (score -1):

Consider module [Single Page Site](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site) - not to be confused with another the other module Single_Page_Website. It is responsive and not theme dependent. When the question was posted, the module didn't exist; only came out recently in 2014.